# I need explanation why the output is a-b c-d

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;  
        while(x > 0) {      
            if(x > 2) {
                System.out.print("a"); 
            }

            x = x - 1;
            System.out.print("-");

            if(x == 2) {
                System.out.print("b c");
            }

            if(x == 1) {
                System.out.print("d");
                x = x - 1;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Output: a-b c-d

by the time "b c" is printed the value of x is supposed to be 2, why did "d" get printed as well?

Comment: Because its in a loop.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through  your program's execution and see how the state of variables change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at the snippet closely

```
    int x = 3;  
    while(x > 0) {      
        if(x > 2) {
            System.out.print("a"); 
        }

        x = x - 1;
        System.out.print("-");

        if(x == 2) {
            System.out.print("b c");
        }

        if(x == 1) {
            System.out.print("d");
            x = x - 1;
        }           
    }
```

when loop runs for the first time the value of x is 3 and the following operations happens

```
    while(x > 0) {      
        if(x > 2) {
            System.out.print("a"); // as the value is 3 so it ll print
        }

        x = x - 1; // here value is 2 now
        System.out.print("-"); // it ll be printed all the time the loop runs

        if(x == 2) {
            System.out.print("b c"); // again this ll be printed because the value is 2
        }

        if(x == 1) {
            System.out.print("d");
            x = x - 1;
        }           
    }
```

now the value of x is 2 and the following operations happen

```
    while(x > 0) {   // value of x is 2   
        if(x > 2) {
            System.out.print("a"); // it is skipped as the value of x is 2
        }

        x = x - 1; // now the value of x is 1
        System.out.print("-"); // it gets printed again

        if(x == 2) {
            System.out.print("b c"); // it gets skipped as the value is 1
        }

        if(x == 1) {
            System.out.print("d"); // it gets printed 
            x = x - 1; // loop gets over here as the value becomes 0
        }           
    }
```

i have simplified it so that you understand well :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the loop runs until X == 0, which means it will run once and print a, bc, Then it checks if X==0, which it isnt, x = x-1, now x == 1 and prints d. The loop runs once more, makes x == 0, and then it stops

```
First round - X == 3, so it prints "a",
X = X - 1, Now x == 2
X== 2, so it prints "bc"
jumps over the last if statement since x > 1.

Second round
X is not 3 so it doesnt print.
X = X -1, now x == 1,
X is not 2, so now print, 
X== 1 so it prints d.

third round since X > 0
only thing happening is X = X -1;
now X == 0, and the while loop will end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to go through the code like a debugger. Line after line.

You see you have your program wrapped in a **while loop**, `while(x>0)` means the whole block of the code will be repeated as long as x is bigger than 0.

**While 1st iteration**

You are right in first iteration after "b c" is printed out the value of x is 2. and program will skip printing "d". At this point the while loop 1st iteration is over.

**While 2nd iteration**

Now the condition of the while is checked x is 2, that means (x > 0) and program will enter the second iteration of the while loop. "a" will not be printed. x is getting decreased to 1. "b-c" will not be printed. As x is 1 "d" will be printed to console.

**While 3rd iteration**

Condition checks value of x. x=1, its bigger then zero so again while loop executes. This time x is decreased to 0. Nothing gets printed as none of the if statements is satisfied.

**End**

As x is 0, its not bigger than 0 anymore, condition of the while loop is not satisfied. While loop will not be executed and program will end.

Check and play with the while loop

[Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_while_loop.asp)